# Can't set up wireless drivers on MSI Stealth, no output returned from lspci

Tags: wireless, drivers, laptop, msi

Installed Ubuntu as dual boot with windows on an MSI GS70 laptop.

Can't get wireless to show up in the toolbar & there are no software updates that appear under "System Settings | Additional Drivers". When I try to determine my wireless card using `lspci -nn -d 14e4:` nothing is returned.

Running `sudo lshw -C network` returns the following:

```
"
 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 13
       serial: 44:8a:5b:6e:e9:a4
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.0.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:42 memory:f7400000-f743ffff ioport:c000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:33 memory:f6800000-f69fffff"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your device, Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter, requires firmware which is not installed by default. Please download this package to your desktop: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.149.3_all.deb

Now, open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

It will probably also benefit from a driver parameter. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working.